# How to print results from a data set using a scientific formula?

Tags: python, for-loop, formula, temperature

I'm having trouble writing this code; I'm given two lists (temperature and pressure) and I need to loop these data values to calculate the potential temperature of each value. 
Potential temperature= T(1000/P)^(R/Cp), where R and Cp are constants (which is the exponent). These constants are:

```
R=287
Cp=1004
The data given is:
Temp=[332.,335., 340., 336., 341.] 
Pressure=[970, 981, 984, 972, 992]
```

How can I set up a code using for-loop so I can print the temperature, pressure, and potential temperature with the same index line by line?

```
import math 
Temp=[332.,335.,340.,336.,341.] 
Pressure=[970,981,984,972,992] 
Potential_Temperature=[] 
for i in range(len(Pressure)): 
    PT=math.pow((1000/Pressure[i]),(287/1004)) 
    Potential_Temperature.append(PT) 
    print(Temp) 
    print(Pressure) 
    print(Potential_Temperature)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: you don't need a loop if you use the pandas library and put your data into a Dataframe than you can apply the formula on setting up a new column for the frame( see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Comment: Look up the documentation for `zip`

Comment: @Andrew I have tried this:
import math

Temp=[332.,335.,340.,336.,341.]
Pressure=[970,981,984,972,992]
Potential_Temperature=[]
for i in range(len(Pressure)):
   PT=math.pow((1000/Pressure[i]),(287/1004))
   Potential_Temperature.append(PT)
  
print(Temp)
print(Pressure)
print(Potential_Temperature)

However, it is not printing the correct potential temperature values.

Comment: @Exi unfortunately I cannot use pandas in this problem, it must be a for-loop.

Comment: It's good practice to include what you have tried, along with an expected output and the output you've obtained, so that your specific issue can be more easily identified.

Comment: @Andrew thank you for the tips, I really appreciate as I'm new here!

Comment: You're also printing the whole lists `Temp` and `Pressure` each time around the loop. I suspect you wanted `print(Temp[i])` and `print(Pressure[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to multiply by the temperature. Try:

```
PT=Temperature[i]*math.pow((1000/Pressure[i]),(287/1004))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function to do the maths that you're after:

```
R=287
Cp=1004
The data given is:
Temp=[332.,335., 340., 336., 341.] 
Pressure=[970, 981, 984, 972, 992]
```

I'm not completely clear from your question whether you want (T*(1000/P))^(R/Cp) or T * ((1000/P)^(R/Cp)) although my maths is a little rusty, they might even be equivalent

```
def potential_temp(temp, pressure, constants):
    r, cp = constants
    temp * ((1000/pressure) ** (r/cp))
    return temp

for temp, pressure in zip(Temp, Pressure):
    print(temp)
    print(pressure)
    print(potential_temp(temp, pressure, (R, Cp))
```

Comment: I meant T*((1000/P)^(R/Cp)), sorry about that. You are also correct about the printing suggestion, I ended up backspacing the prints so it's out of the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Theta = []
for i in range(len(Temp)):
    PT=Temp[i]*math.pow((1000/Pressure[i]),(R/Cp))
    Theta.append(PT)
```

Comment: This is non pythonic. Use a list comprehension and zip.